# Matrix Decomposition as $M=AA^\intercal$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am interested in decomposing a square $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with positive integer elements as a square matrix $A$ with positive integer elements and such that $M=AA^\intercal$. I have a couple of questions regarding this decomposition:

1. Is there a criterion for determining if this decomposition is possible? I think it is necessary for $M$ to be positive semi-definitive, but I am not sure this is enough to ensure a decomposition over positive integer elements.
2. Is this decomposition unique? I think it is at least unique up to some unitary  equivalence.
3. Is there an algorithm to compute the decomposition of $M$?
4. Is there a difference in above statements (can we make some statements stronger or relax them) if we allow non-square $A$?

Comment: To question 2) If $M=AA^\top$, then $M=BB^\top$ for $B=-A$.

Comment: In that case $B$ would have negative values, since $A$ contains only positive inetegers, hence $B$ would not be allowed. I am specifically searching for solutions were $A$ can only contain zeros or positive integers.

Comment: $\det M = (\det A)^2$ needs to be a square

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ does not admit a Cholesky decomposition over the semiring $\Bbb Z_+$, although it is positive semi-definite. See also [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03081087.2018.1529137) which may answer some of your other questions.

Comment: are you talking about a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In some sense I am talking about matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ but I am restricting M and $A$ to only have elements in $\mathbb{Z_+}$, which I know is not a field. So it feels weird to say I am talking about a matrix over $\mathbb{Z_+}$.